# Stats on Area51 seems to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed

The Site Stats on Area51 seems to be broken.

150 users with 200+ rep (**currently 0 users** with 200+ rep)

10 users with 2,000+ rep (currently 0 users with 2,000+ rep)

5 users with 3,000+ rep (currently 0 users with 3,000+ rep)

Link: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51674/open-data

Answer (score 1):

It's working now with 85 users with 200+ and 2 users with 2,000+ showing.  Must have been an interim issue.

Comment: Probably yes, because it showed also about 50 questions per day. Maybe a cached problem and now it's ok.

Comment: Yep, Nick fixed this yesterday: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234383/who-borked-the-area-51-stats. (cc @AnastasiosVentouris)